# Merge master in another branch

Tags: git

Supposedly two people are working on a project and one of them, unknowingly from the other, creates a new branch in the project. Now, say the first person keeps on pushing changes to the master branch and the other branch gets outdated. How can I push the changes of master branch in to this outdated branch. 
For the sake of discussion, let's name that outdated branch as 'outdated-branch'.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have yout tried to merge `master` into `outdated-branch`?

```
git checkout outdated-branch
git merge master
```

Comment: This seems right but a silly/newbie question: wouldn't checking out outdated-branch locally override my code to outdared-branch's latest commit, herego outdating the code?

Comment: Yes but the code is commited to master if I understood your question correctly so its safe

Comment: Well, yes. And merging `master` you'll get the latest changes from master. If you have uncommited changes in your directory, which would be overwritten by the `checkout`, git will prevent you from checking it out.

Comment: Thank you, guys. It worked like a charm! I wish I could accept both answers but, @Trudbert, I gave yours an upvote :) Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways: merge and rebase

First:

```
git checkout outdated-branch
```

Then merge:

```
git merge master
```

or rebase:

```
git rebase master
```

A discussion on advantages and disadvantages of either can be found [here](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/10/git-team-workflows-merge-or-rebase/). The history of outdated-branch will look different other than that they produce the same result (including the same conflicts).

Comment: Let me check that out after taking a backup of local branch. Mind with my silly ways, I am new with git :)